# Backup and restore the subsite

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration

I have some issues with migrating a sub site from one site collection to another site collection. Can you please let me know what should I need to do to achieve this?
Regards

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Which version you're using? For SharePoint on-premise, you could use [Export-SPWeb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/Export-SPWeb?view=sharepoint-ps) and [Import-SPWeb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/Import-SPWeb?view=sharepoint-ps).

Comment: Thanks for your message, I have tried the Export command, I was expecting to see only one .CMP file, however in the Path I have specified there are hundreds of file.Starting with filename1 to filename350. Please see the attached file.

Comment: Check this thread https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/ee00fec2-4c55-40c5-9ced-129c2c63f209/sharepoint-multiple-cmps-on-exportspweb-powershell-command?forum=sharepointadmin